# Distance and other stuff between two Location in C# / WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

How can I get the distance between two `Location` in C#?
It also would be very nice to get the direction between two Locations if I have the compass value of the device.

is there any api for this?

Comment: I think this control can do that (http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/) it's open source, you'll have to dig around for the right bit.

Comment: please run the query 'distance between two lat longs' through google.  This has been covered so many times here and many other places - it's no difference for a windows store application

Comment: Assuming you mean two Lat/Lon coordinates (you should be more specific in your questions. Two locations X & Y?), you can use the Great Circle method to calculate distance between two Lat/Lon coordinates: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance Otherwise, use the Pythagorean theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem

Comment: I dont want to do it on my own, I would like to use a already existing api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.
What do you mean by **Location**?

**Case 1: When location is geographic point (Latitude, Longitude)**

You need to go through spherical geometry. In fact you should make some calculation on a sphere (or Ellipsoid or other Spheroids). But the best way to avoid doing such complicated calculation is to use `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll` (v.10 or v.11). If you have SQL Server 2012 (or 2008) installed on your system, you can find it somewhere like this (otherwise you may download it from the web):

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Shared\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll"
```

Then using this dll you can declare two `SqlGeography` type and call the `STDistance()` method and everything will be done correctly. (Remember there are lost of issue here, I'm not going to complicate it more than this). Here is the code:

```
SqlGeography p1 =
SqlGeography.STPointFromText(new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlChars("POINT( lat1, long1)"), 4326); // SRID of WGS84: 4326

SqlGeography p2 =
SqlGeography.STPointFromText(new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlChars("POINT( lat2, long2)"), 4326); // SRID of WGS84: 4326

double distance = p1.STDistance(p2).Value;
```

**Case 2: When location is a simple local 2D point (x, y) on a plane**

In this case you can use the famous formula to calculate the distance:

```
double distance = Math.Sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy); //dx and dy are the difference of the x and y of the two points
```